# RSpec test DSL instance_eval method

Tags: ruby, rspec

i'm trying to do some tests here. I have a DSL and a class that evals it. I would like to test the method that evaluates the DSL methods, but I don't know how to pass a &block as an argument in rspec.

This is my DSL

```
animal 'Cat' do
  likes :eating, :sleeping
  dislikes :dogs
end
```

This is my Earth.rb file which evaluates the method:

```
def animal(name, &block)
    animal = Animal.new(name)
    animal.instance_eval(&block)
    @animals << animals
end
```

And this is my spec file that I'm trying to run:

```
describe '.animal' do
    context 'with correct block' do
      it "creates a set of animals" do
        expect(earth.animal('Cat', "likes :sugar, :cinema dislikes :dogs")).
          to be something
      end
    end
  end
```

What would be the apropiate way to pass that block that is not working?
thanks!

Comment: Why not calling exactly as in the example you give at the top of the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
block = lambda do
  likes :sugar, :cinema 
  dislikes :dogs
end
expect(earth.animal('Cat', &block)).to be something
```

Comment: i get a ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0). on the line where i define the block, any idea?

Comment: Can you show your likes and dislikes method definitions?

Comment: `def likes(*set_of_likes)
   @like = set_of_likes
  end

  def dislikes(*set_of_dislikes)
   @dislike = set_of_dislikes
  end`

Comment: Also, can you paste the stack trace of your error? Is it happening while defining the block or calling it? IRB output from my machine: `irb(main):001:0> block = lambda do
irb(main):002:1*   likes :sugar, :cinema
irb(main):003:1>   dislikes :dogs
irb(main):004:1> end
=> #<Proc:0x007f80fa913b38@(irb):1 (lambda)>
irb(main):005:0> `

Comment: `Failure/Error: expect(cupid.person('Kitty', block)).to be_nil
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./lib/exercise6/earth.rb:17:in `animals'
     # ./spec/spec_earth.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>`

Comment: Well, your code has `animal` while the failure example has `person`. Also, I noticed that your `expect` is syntactically not correct. Use `expect{ cupid.person('Kitty', block) }.to be_nil` instead.

Comment: ok, i did a bad copy pasting, but thats the idea. and it works with brackets either way. thats not solving my problem dude